# How to send an object as argument when a UIButton is tapped?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uibutton

I have the following code inside my UIViewController -

```
[flipButton addTarget:self.navigationController.delegate action:@selector(changeModeAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

As you can see, it calls a method inside it's navigation controller delegate. How do I correctly pass along an object to this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use objc_setAssociatedObject and objc_getAssociatedObject

Comment: Is this documented or private API bound to get rejected by Apple?

Comment: Look in the documentation. Try "Objective-C Runtime Reference".

Comment: Could You please explain by or sample code or any link,that would be really helpful.Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can use the layer property. Add the object you want to pass as the value in the layer dictionary.

```
[[btn layer] setValue:yourObj forKey:@"yourKey"];
```

This `yourObj` is accessible from the button action function:

```
-(void)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    yourObj = [[sender layer] valueForKey:@"yourKey"];
}
```

With this method you can pass multiple values to the button function just by adding new objects in the dictionary with different keys.

Answer (score 1):

When `changeModeAction:` is called `flipButton` should pass itself as the sender. If you need additional parameters passed you could [create a category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500327/subclass-uibutton-to-add-a-property/5500525#5500525) for the type of flipButton to store additional information or you could set up a dictionary that the navigationController can access e.g.

```
if(sender == flipButton)
 id obj = [someDictionary objectForKey:@"flipButtonKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

extension + Swift 3.0

```
extension NSObject {

fileprivate struct ObjectTagKeys {
    static var ObjectTag = "ObjectTag"
}

func setObjectTag(_ tag:Any!) {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &ObjectTagKeys.ObjectTag, tag, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
}

func getObjectTag() -> Any
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &ObjectTagKeys.ObjectTag)
}

}
```